# Saving form data to cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies

I've been trying to solve this problem for about a week now with no luck. I'm trying to save a value from a form field to a cookie onclick="updatePricingFunction() but when I click the updatePricingFunction button attached to the onclick, the value doesn't change to the new number. Can anyone help me with this?

```
function updatePricingFunction(){
 var beforeNoonField = document.getElementById("beforeNoonNPSlot"); // beforeNoonNPSlot is a form id.
    document.cookie = "beforeNoonCookie=" + beforeNoonField; // Create the cookie
```

}

Comment: if "beforeNoonNPSlot" is the form's id, then beforeNoonField is the form DOM element.  "beforeNoonCookie=" + beforeNoonField would equal "beforeNoonCookie=[object HTMLFormElement]" You probably want to store the value of the field not forms's toString result.

Comment: what is the value you want to store on cookies ?? I see that you want to put the whole form (the HTMLFormElement) on cookies which doesn't make sense ... document.cookie supports only values like strings or integers

Comment: So are you saying to just change the last line of code to document.cookie ="beforeNoonCookie=" + beforeNoonField.toString()

Comment: In response to Khalid, I want to store the value on a cookie because I want the value to change on a form and that value to stay when I close and reopen the browser.

Answer (score 0):

lol your code was a bit wrong, but say for argument's sake, you had

```
<form name="myform">
     Enter Number<input type="text" name="sampletext" id="beforeNoonNPSlot">
     <button type="button" onclick="updatePricingFunction()">Set Cookie</button>
</form>
```

you need to get the name of your form and the name of the texbox where you want to get the value from. So that when the button is clicked the function updatePricingFunction() will be called, it will retrive the value from The textbox in your form

```
 function updatePricingFunction()
 {
      //To get a value in a text field, you must have your variable equals
      //document.forms["(form name here)"]["(name of the text field here)"].value
      var beforeNoonField = document.forms["myform"]["sampletext"].value;//This gets your value 
      document.cookie = "beforeNoonCookie=" + beforeNoonField; // Create the cookie
 }
```

Take note that this method is a more conventional method of getting values with javascript so you should be using this more often.

Comment: I replaced my code with yours Programming Newb, but nothing changes. The pricing stays the same. I'n not really sure how this ties into the pricing field too where I enter the quantity. That field looks like this  <input type="text" id="beforeNoon" class="input-small" placeholder="Before Noon">

Comment: Did you try using alerts to see if the javascript saved the value? when i tried it, i got the value that i inputted in the code, if not it would be the cookies that i had problems with, can you create a Fiddle for your code?

Comment: I couldn't jsfiddle to work properly for some reason, but here it is on a similar site. http://jsbin.com/siribuje/2/edit?html,css,output The set cookie field is assigned to the before noon textbox